Is there a way to connect users from different projects?
My admin dashboard users are in mongodb in authentication server(expressjs ts) but my apps users are in postgresql in another server(Django). I have made once service that is used to create events. but the problem is I want to know who created the event. as the event can be created by both admin users and app users.
I am currently using jwt with same secret in both servers and using bearer token to authenticate the user. So far it's working as I am storing the id and name of users in event model. here the id of admin will be from mongodb and id of app user will be from postgresql. Is there a correct way to do this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
